# How can I connect a 5 1/4" floppy drive to my modern PC?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, hardware, dos

I have a small collection of 5 1/4" floppy disks (early Sierra games) that I am trying to read.  How can I connect a drive that accepts these disks to my PC.

This has been moved over to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/513887/how-do-i-connect-a-5-1-4-floopy-drive-to-a-modern-pc)

Comment: According to the FAQ hardware related issues relevant to gaming are appropriate.  I have old PC games on 5 1/4" disks and while attempting to make this work in DOSBox I happened on this product, I wanted to share it.

Comment: That's a good thing to add to your question, then.  Context is important, otherwise it sounds like something that belongs on SuperUser. :P

Comment: I still think it belongs on Super User

Comment: Fair enough.  I've been building out a collection of [80's and 90's gaming stuff](http://pinterest.com/sperske/90-s-themed-guest-bedroom/) and as I start working on the PC side I'm looking for some place more useful than a blog to store things I've been finding to make old hardware work.

Answer (score 6):

A company called [Device Side Data](http://www.deviceside.com/) produces a device called the [FC5025](http://www.deviceside.com/fc5025.html) which can adapt a 5 1/4" drive to a USB port.  You will still need to power the drive so this approach will require either an external power source or a tower or desktop computer.  There are also other limitations to this device, such as the inability to write to the disks or to read most forms of copy protection (back when these drives were common there was a technique to protect their contents form copying by writing intentionally bad data).

Using just original hardware the best approach would be to build or buy a computer that had a 5 1/4" inch drive and could connect to a network or had a 3 1/2" drive as well. 3 1/2" drives are still common enough to find as USB external drives, while networking a old PC would be complex.